# How do i declare this and set values later? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code I have and it is not working. I dunno how to declare this

```
    var input = {
        container: '.slide_container',
        container_all: '.slide_show',
        slides: []
    };

    var $slides = $('.slide_show .slide');
    var l = $slides.length;

    for( var i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
        input.slides[i].el = '#' + $slides.eq(i).attr('id');
        if( i === 0 ) {
            input.slides[i].weight = 1;
        } else {
            input.slides[i].weight = 0;
        }
    }
```

When it gets to

```
input.slides[i].el = '#' + $slides.eq(i).attr('id');
```

it says the input.slides[i].el is undefined. Can someone let me know the correct way to declare the empty slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your object first.  Something like:

```
input.slides[i] = { el: '#' + $slides.eq(i).attr('id'), weight: 0 };
```

You also might want to consider using `push` to add to your array.

```
input.slides.push({ el: '#' + $slides.eq(i).attr('id'), weight: 0 }); //Add new object to the array
```

Comment: understood, I didn't realize that it was not initialized, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `input.slides[i]` before assign something to its attribute.

```
for( var i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
    input.slides[i] = {};
    input.slides[i].el = '#' + $slides.eq(i).attr('id');
    if( i === 0 ) {
        input.slides[i].weight = 1;
    } else {
        input.slides[i].weight = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: this works as well, I give it to the above because he was 30 secs faster, I thumbed your answer as it works perfectly as well